# New style python buffer protocol and numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, python-c-api, pep3118

I'm trying to write a fast non copy interface for my python binding of a commercial image processing library. I implemented the new-style buffer api protocol which looks ok according to memoryview():

```
import hirsch as H
import numpy as np

w,h = 7,5
img = H.HImage.GenImageConst('byte',w,h)
m = memoryview(img)
print 'ndim shape=',m.ndim,m.shape
# -> 2 (5L, 7L)
```

What I don't understand is why numpy doesn't catch this interface?

```
a = np.array(img)
print 'ndim size shape=',a.ndim,a.size,a.shape
# -> 0 1 ()
```

Am I doing something wrong, or should I just resort to using the numpy array interface, which works, though it copies the data?

Note that I'm using python 2.7

Comment: It may be that there's something surprising going on --- but it's difficult to say what without knowing what is in your implementation of `bf_getbuffer` and `bf_releasebuffer`. The new buffer interface is supposed to work also on Python 2.x (indeed: `np.array(memoryview('asd')) == np.array([ 97, 115, 100], dtype=np.uint8)`. (Note also that the Numpy array interface does not need to copy the data.)

Answer (score 3):

The `np.array` function expects an *array-like* object, not a buffer:

> `array(object, dtype=None, copy=True, order=None, subok=False, ndmin=0)`
>
> Create an array.
>
> object : array_like
>      An array, any object exposing the array interface, an
>      object whose `__array__` method returns an array, or any
>      (nested) sequence.

If you want to create an array from a buffer you should use `np.frombuffer`:

> `frombuffer(buffer, dtype=float, count=-1, offset=0)`
>
> Interpret a buffer as a 1-dimensional array.
>
> buffer : buffer_like
>       An object that exposes the buffer interface.

Currently your object, as far as numpy is concerned, is a scalar:

```
In [7]: a=np.array(1)

In [8]: a.ndim,a.size,a.shape
Out[8]: (0, 1, ())
```

Comment: If the new buffer is the standard python interface, I'm surprised that np array does not support it! I figured out that the following line can be used for the conversion: `a = np.frombuffer(m.tobytes(),{'i8':'i1'}[m.format]).reshape(m.shape)`. But it also involves copying in m.tobytes().

Comment: The new buffer interface is supported also in `np.array`: `np.array(memoryview(np.array([1,2,3]))).shape == (3,)`. The reason for the difference may be in the implementation of the custom object's getbuffer...

Comment: I got it to work in the end. One issue that confused me is that you need to use the `copy=False` argument to `np.array()` in order to get a reference to the same memory.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try `np.asarray`. I had success with it but I don't have access to hirsch so I can't test it.

BTW, Bakuriu has it right: you are creating a scalar array (ndim 0, size 1) of type `np.object`.